# Restrict REST API access to only my website

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, rest, security

I created MongoDB and Node.js REST API for my website. I am accessing my database data from the API and showing it on my website. I am doing these things locally on `localhost`.

Now I want to host my REST API. I don't have any idea regarding hosting. If I host my REST API somewhere and start getting data through its endpoints, then anybody can use those endpoints and access my data, but I want to restrict it to my website only. Meaning, that only my website can make requests to that API, no other websites can make a request. If other websites try to access it, it should show an error. How can I achieve this? Can someone please explain me step by step how do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are referring to CORS. You need to set your API to have a  response header  like this on all requests:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://yourSiteDomain.com

You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Other people can still access your API directly though, through postman etc.

Comment: is there any way so that others cannot access

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a CSRF(cross site request forgery) token

 for node js you can use 
csurf : http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/csurf.html

look online on how to implment it